# assigning a function to a name globally

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, jint

I need a javascript function `f` that given another (anonymous) function `g` and a name `n` will assign `g` to that name in the global scope (or at least the current scope). I should be able to use it like this:

```
f(function(){ /* code */ }, "foo");

foo(); // this call should now work!
```

Is this possible? I need a pure JavaScript solution, no DOM-stuff or anything like that. This is not intended to run in any browser..

*Disclaimer: I may or may not have a good/valid reason for wanting to do this. You do not need to lecture me on the virtue of keeping the global scope clean etc. ;)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Reid

```
function f(g, n) {
    this[n] = g;
}
```

Or to be safer:

```
function f(g, n) {
    (function() { return this; })()[n] = g;
}
```

Comment: window is not pure js I believe. I'm not in a browser and have no window.

Comment: @Torbjørn: Which environment are you writing this in? I need more info to properly answer your question

Comment: @Torbjørn: then replace window with whatever your global object is, or retrieve the global object, if you are unaware of it by name, by running `(function () { return this; }())` in non-strict-mode code.

Comment: @Torbjørn in javascript i beleive you need a parent object. if you `var myNewVariable = some_value;` and then `this.myNewVariable` it will return `some_value`. I'd find a spec that shows this... but i'm not THAT smart ;)

Comment: @Reid: I tried running that, but get nothing back. The environment is Jint, a JavaScript interpreter in .NET. I guess this should have been a Jint-specific question.. :|

Comment: @Torbjørn: I added a jint tag to the question

Comment: @Torbjørn: for reference, which method did you use?

Comment: I used function f(g, n) { this[n] = g; }. That is, I replaced window with this in the original suggestion.

Comment: The "safer" version will error in ES5 strict mode as `this` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be compliant wtih ES5 strict mode, then you'll need:

```
var addGlobalFunction = (function(global) {
    return function (fn, name) {
        global[name] = fn;
    };
})(this);
```

A reference to the global object is kept in a closure. However it's hard to see why such a function might be necessary.

Comment: Do you have a reference explaining why this is needed to be compliant?